# How to read file line by line using open read?

Tags: c, file

i have a file contain some commands :
example : the file named  commands.txt

i want to read every command from file for i can execute them

methods : open() , read() , exec (execlp or execvp ..)

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <fcntl.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 #define bufSize 1024
 int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
 {
   int fp;
   char buf[bufSize];

   fp = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);

   while (read(fp , buf, sizeof(buf)) != 0)
   {
      buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = '\0'; 
      printf("%s\n", buf);
   }
      close(fp);
      return 0;
   }
```

i try this code but it return the whole file into string ..

Comment: The `read()` function doesn't care about newlines.  You do.  You're going to have to match your desires to `read()`'s behaviour.  You need to decide how you can buffer lines so that if you get more than one line of input, you dole it out in line-sized pieces. That's why standard I/O streams (usually) have a buffer. Your code only fits the whole file into the string if the whole file is small enough. Are you sure your files contain no null bytes? You should be recording the length returned by `read()` and using that to decide where to place your null byte; `read()` does not null-terminate data.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler thanks for your explanation , yes i'm sure that the file doesnt contain a null byte

Comment: Are you familiar with structures yet?  Why do you have to use `read()`?  Why not use POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) or even standard C 
[`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) if you're interested in lines?  Do you want newlines preserved?  Do you want to (need to) map `\r\n` to `\n`?  Do you need to handle lines that end `\r` (instead of `\n` or `\r\n`)?  Why does it matter whether the whole file is read at once?  The code shown doesn't depend on it being split into lines.

Comment: i agree with you , it's easy to use fgets and getLine but it's problem asked by professor : this is the task : Write a q4.c program that allows you to execute a command list stored in a file (one command per line) and save their results to a file. The names of the two files are provided as arguments (using read() , write() , exec family)

Answer (score 2):

There are probably endless improvements that can be made to this, but it more or less does the job.

```
/* SO 4896-8349 */
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static char *arg0;

static void execute_string(int fd, char *cmd);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    arg0 = argv[0];
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s cmds output\n", arg0);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int fd1 = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (fd1 < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file %s for reading (%d: %s)\n",
                arg0, argv[1], errno, strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int fd2 = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_APPEND, 0644);
    if (fd2 < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file %s for writing (%d: %s)\n",
                arg0, argv[2], errno, strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    dup2(fd2, STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(fd2);

    char buffer[64];
    char *bufend = buffer + sizeof(buffer);
    char *str = buffer;
    ssize_t nbytes;

    while ((nbytes = read(fd1, str, bufend - str)) > 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Read: [[[%.*s]]]\n", (int)nbytes, str);
        size_t tbytes = (str + nbytes) - buffer;
        fprintf(stderr, "Data: [[[%.*s]]]\n", (int)tbytes, buffer);
        char *base = buffer;
        char *eol;
        while ((eol = memchr(base, '\n', tbytes - (base - buffer))) != 0)
        {
            *eol = '\0';
            fprintf(stderr, "Line: [[[%s]]]\n", base);
            execute_string(fd1, base);
            base = eol + 1;
        }
        size_t ebytes = buffer + tbytes - base;
        if (ebytes > 0)
            memmove(buffer, base, buffer + tbytes - base);
        str = buffer + ebytes;
        fprintf(stderr, "Residue: [[[%.*s]]]\n", (int)(str - buffer), buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}

static void execute_string(int fd, char *cmd)
{
    char *args[] = { "sh", "-c", cmd, 0 };
    printf("Cmd: [%s]\n", cmd);
    fflush(0);
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to fork (%d: %s)\n",
                arg0, errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        close(fd);
        execvp(args[0], args);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to execute shell to run '%s' (%d: %s)\n",
                arg0, cmd, errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int corpse;
    int status;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: PID %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n",
                arg0, corpse, status);
    }
}
```

The code sets up to read from the file specified by `argv[1]` and arranges for all standard output to go to the file specified by `argv[2]`.  It leaves standard input untouched so that the commands executed will read as normal.

The code in `main()` reads blocks of data (64 bytes at a time here, for testing, so I get to test it easily — the buffer size should be far bigger for 'production' work).  It then splits each block into a sequence of lines and possibly a residue with no newline in it.  It zaps thhe newline with a null byte to create a string, closes the input file descriptor `fd1` and passes the string to the `execute_string()` function.  That invokes the shell to execute the command — you can do a more complex code (split the string into command and arguments, maybe handling I/O redirection and pipes and so on), or simpler code (use `system()`).

It also keeps track of the as-yet unprocessed data from each block, and reads more data when there is no newline left.  The code hasn't been tested on a file which doesn't end with a newline; if that's a problem, you'll need to change the code (probably adding code to execute the residue after loop controlled by the `read()` fails).

On standard error, it reports the process as it goes; on standard output, it writes the command executed and lets the commands write their output too.

For example, with the input file `cmds.txt` containing:

```
ls -l $HOME/src/sqltools/sqlcmd/Test/sqlcmd
ls -l $HOME/src/sqltools/sqlcmd/Test/sqlreload
ls -l $HOME/src/sqltools/sqlcmd/Test/sqlunload
ls -l $HOME/src/sqltools/sqlcmd/Test/sqlupload
ls -l $HOME/src/sqltools/sqlcmd/Test/tools
ls -l $HOME/lib
ls -l $HOME/bin
ls -l $HOME/etc
ls -l $HOME/inc
```

(where all those directories exist), then I get output like:

```
$ rcmd47 cmds.txt cmds.out
Read: [[[ls -l $HOME/src/sqltools/sqlcmd/Test/sqlcmd
ls -l $HOME/src/sqlt]]]
Data: [[[ls -l $HOME/src/sqltools/sqlcmd/Test/sqlcmd
ls -l $HOME/src/sqlt]]]
Line: [[[ls -l $HOME/src/sqltools/sqlcmd/Test/sqlcmd]]]
rcmd47: PID 48774 exited with status 0x0000
Residue: [[[ls -l $HOME/src/sqlt]]]
Read: [[[ools/sqlcmd/Test/sqlreload
ls -l $HOME/src/s]]]
Data: [[[ls -l $HOME/src/sqltools/sqlcmd/Test/sqlreload
ls -l $HOME/src/s]]]
Line: [[[ls -l $HOME/src/sqltools/sqlcmd/Test/sqlreload]]]
rcmd47: PID 48775 exited with status 0x0000
Residue: [[[ls -l $HOME/src/s]]]
Read: [[[qltools/sqlcmd/Test/sqlunload
ls -l $HOME/src/s]]]
Data: [[[ls -l $HOME/src/sqltools/sqlcmd/Test/sqlunload
ls -l $HOME/src/s]]]
Line: [[[ls -l $HOME/src/sqltools/sqlcmd/Test/sqlunload]]]
rcmd47: PID 48776 exited with status 0x0000
Residue: [[[ls -l $HOME/src/s]]]
Read: [[[qltools/sqlcmd/Test/sqlupload
ls -l $HOME/src/s]]]
Data: [[[ls -l $HOME/src/sqltools/sqlcmd/Test/sqlupload
ls -l $HOME/src/s]]]
Line: [[[ls -l $HOME/src/sqltools/sqlcmd/Test/sqlupload]]]
rcmd47: PID 48777 exited with status 0x0000
Residue: [[[ls -l $HOME/src/s]]]
Read: [[[qltools/sqlcmd/Test/tools
ls -l $HOME/lib
ls -l]]]
Data: [[[ls -l $HOME/src/sqltools/sqlcmd/Test/tools
ls -l $HOME/lib
ls -l]]]
Line: [[[ls -l $HOME/src/sqltools/sqlcmd/Test/tools]]]
rcmd47: PID 48778 exited with status 0x0000
Line: [[[ls -l $HOME/lib]]]
rcmd47: PID 48779 exited with status 0x0000
Residue: [[[ls -l]]]
Read: [[[ $HOME/bin
ls -l $HOME/etc
ls -l $HOME/inc
]]]
Data: [[[ls -l $HOME/bin
ls -l $HOME/etc
ls -l $HOME/inc
]]]
Line: [[[ls -l $HOME/bin]]]
rcmd47: PID 48780 exited with status 0x0000
Line: [[[ls -l $HOME/etc]]]
rcmd47: PID 48781 exited with status 0x0000
Line: [[[ls -l $HOME/inc]]]
rcmd47: PID 48782 exited with status 0x0000
Residue: [[[]]]
$
```

and the output files `cmds.out` contains (trimmed):

```
Cmd: [ls -l $HOME/src/sqltools/sqlcmd/Test/sqlcmd]
total 64
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   515 Jul 13  2008 Makefile
drwxr-xr-x  36 jleffler  staff  1152 Aug  1  2008 Miscellany
drwxr-xr-x  10 jleffler  staff   320 Jul 28  2016 RCS
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff    61 Jan 20  2015 lvc.unl
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff    59 Jan 20  2015 lvc2.unl
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   194 Jul 14  2008 t00version.sh
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff  2250 Jul 14  2008 t02varchar.sh
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff  1985 Jul 14  2008 t03boolean.sh
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff  2649 Jul 10  2015 t04lvarchar.sh
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   867 Jul 14  2008 t05text.sh
Cmd: [ls -l $HOME/src/sqltools/sqlcmd/Test/sqlreload]
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  77 Aug  1  2000 Makefile
Cmd: [ls -l $HOME/src/sqltools/sqlcmd/Test/sqlunload]
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  77 Aug  1  2000 Makefile
Cmd: [ls -l $HOME/src/sqltools/sqlcmd/Test/sqlupload]
total 32
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff   300 Apr 10  2006 Makefile
drwxr-xr-x  4 jleffler  staff   128 Mar 21  2007 RCS
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff    84 Jul 14  2008 reject.log
-rwxr-x--x  1 jleffler  staff  1552 Jul 12  2000 rejlog
-rw-r-----  1 jleffler  staff  1642 Apr 10  2006 t01rejlog.sh
Cmd: [ls -l $HOME/src/sqltools/sqlcmd/Test/tools]
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  7 jleffler  staff   224 Dec 28  2013 RCS
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jleffler  staff  1302 May 12  2011 stt_run
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jleffler  staff  4947 May 12  2011 stt_test
-rwxr-xr-x  1 jleffler  staff  2449 Dec 28  2013 stt_testsuite
Cmd: [ls -l $HOME/lib]
total 40
drwxr-xr-x    4 jleffler  staff    128 Jan 26 21:18 32
drwxr-xr-x   12 jleffler  staff    384 Jan 24 19:57 64
drwxr-xr-x   21 jleffler  staff    672 Feb 23 14:46 AFF
drwxr-xr-x    9 jleffler  staff    288 Feb 23 14:47 Awk
…
drwxr-xr-x    3 jleffler  staff     96 Jan  6  2016 unpv13e-jl
-r--r--r--    1 jleffler  staff   7153 Oct 30  1998 yypars
Cmd: [ls -l $HOME/bin]
total 20352
lrwxr-xr-x    1 jleffler  staff        9 Jan 22  2016 12.10.FC6 -> osiris_19
-rwxr-xr-x    1 jleffler  staff      636 Oct 30 14:20 2
…
-rwxr-xr-x    1 jleffler  staff     1098 Sep 12  1998 zconcat
-rwxr-xr-x    1 jleffler  staff      156 Aug  7  2002 zcpio
Cmd: [ls -l $HOME/etc]
total 1240
-rw-------    1 jleffler  staff    424 May  7  2012 Isis.local
-r--r--r--    1 jleffler  staff   2258 Apr  8  2017 Makefile
…
-r--------    1 jleffler  staff    572 Apr 27  2016 vimrc.atria
-rw-r--r--    1 jleffler  staff  10632 Oct  9 17:44 yyparse.c
Cmd: [ls -l $HOME/inc]
total 1032
drwxr-xr-x  32 jleffler  staff   1024 Nov  6 11:11 RCS
-r--r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   2970 Mar  1  2015 aff.h
-r--r--r--   2 jleffler  staff   2370 Dec 29 13:20 aomcopy.h
…
-r--r--r--   2 jleffler  staff    864 May 29  2010 wildmat.h
-r--r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   1076 Jul 22  2017 wraphead.h
```

#### Handling long lines and no newline

As noted in the comments, the code above doesn't deal with long lines (lines longer than the fixed size buffer), nor does it handle the last line of the file when it is not terminated by a newline.  Neither is particularly difficult to deal with.  Simply use dynamic allocation for the buffer, and process any residue after the main input loop finishes.  One way of doing it becomes:

```
/* SO 4896-8349 */
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* Handles no newline on last line */
/* Handles command line longer than buffer */

static char *arg0;

static void execute_string(int fd, char *cmd);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    arg0 = argv[0];
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s cmds output\n", arg0);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int fd1 = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    if (fd1 < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file %s for reading (%d: %s)\n",
                arg0, argv[1], errno, strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int fd2 = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_APPEND, 0644);
    if (fd2 < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open file %s for writing (%d: %s)\n",
                arg0, argv[2], errno, strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    dup2(fd2, STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(fd2);

    enum { MAX_BUFFER = 16 };
    size_t bufsiz = MAX_BUFFER;
    char *buffer = malloc(bufsiz + 1);
    if (buffer == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to allocate %zu bytes of memory (%d: %s)\n",
                arg0, bufsiz + 1, errno, strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    char *bufend = buffer + bufsiz;
    char *str = buffer;
    ssize_t nbytes;

    while ((nbytes = read(fd1, str, bufend - str)) > 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Read: [[[%.*s]]]\n", (int)nbytes, str);
        size_t tbytes = (str + nbytes) - buffer;
        fprintf(stderr, "Data: [[[%.*s]]]\n", (int)tbytes, buffer);
        char *base = buffer;
        char *eol;
        while ((eol = memchr(base, '\n', tbytes - (base - buffer))) != 0)
        {
            *eol = '\0';
            fprintf(stderr, "Line: [[[%s]]]\n", base);
            execute_string(fd1, base);
            base = eol + 1;
        }
        size_t ebytes = buffer + tbytes - base;
        if (ebytes > 0)
            memmove(buffer, base, buffer + tbytes - base);
        if (ebytes == bufsiz)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Long: %zu bytes with no newline\n", bufsiz);
            size_t newsiz = 2 * bufsiz;
            char  *newbuf = realloc(buffer, newsiz + 1);
            if (newbuf == 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to allocate %zu bytes of memory (%d: %s)\n",
                        arg0, newsiz + 1, errno, strerror(errno));
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
            buffer = newbuf;
            bufsiz = newsiz;
            bufend = buffer + bufsiz;
        }
        str = buffer + ebytes;
        fprintf(stderr, "Residue: [[[%.*s]]]\n", (int)(str - buffer), buffer);
    }
    if (str != buffer)
    {
        *str = '\0';
        fprintf(stderr, "Part: [[[%s]]]\n", buffer);
        execute_string(fd1, buffer);
    }
    close(fd1);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}

static void execute_string(int fd, char *cmd)
{
    char *args[] = { "sh", "-c", cmd, 0 };
    printf("Cmd: [%s]\n", cmd);
    fflush(0);
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to fork (%d: %s)\n",
                arg0, errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        close(fd);
        execvp(args[0], args);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to execute shell to run '%s' (%d: %s)\n",
                arg0, cmd, errno, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int corpse;
    int status;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: PID %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n",
                arg0, corpse, status);
    }
}
```

The `execute_string()` function is unchanged.  The code starts with a small buffer (mainly to force the reallocation to be tested).  The working buffer size is one byte smaller than the physical size; that allows a null to be added after the last line even if there isn't a newline at the end and the size of the last line is exactly wrong.  The code also closes `fd1` and frees the buffer when the work is complete.  Not 100% necessary, but good housekeeping.

Comment: UV. Minor: if the last "line" lacks a `'\n'`, it remains in `buffer[]`.

Comment: @chux: I did cover that with the observation _The code hasn't been tested on a file which doesn't end with a newline._  The biggest issue would be if that last line has exactly the same number of characters as the buffer; there'd be peril of overflow.  It probably isn't impossible to fix — if only by allocating a spare byte in the buffer and changing things so that 'one less than the buffer size' is used elsewhere.

Comment: The other problem, at least with lines as short as 64 bytes, is "what about if the line of a command is longer than that.  This code doesn't handle it.